# videoFilter - draw text between one time and between another time

Tags: ffmpeg

Well I know we can use drawText for a time range using

> "enable=between(t, 1, 3)" (between 1 sec and 3sec)

but how can I add

> "and draw text between 45 sec to 50 sec".

I can't find out how to add another between condition.

Answer (score 2):

just add

```
enable='between(t,1,3)+between(t,45,50)'
```